# Transmission Remote GUI and file handling (transgui)

Tags: linux, windows, bittorrent

I'm in the process of migrating my headless Linux seedbox and Windows client from deluge, which seems to be no longer supported, to transmission-daemon on the seedbox and Transmission Remote GUI on the client.
My process with deluge was like this: download to a "leech" directory, then do an automatic completion move to a "complete" directory which is shared via samba. Manually copy the new files to my desktop (leave on the seedbox for further seeding) and use the deluge windows client to move them to a "seed" directory.

With Transmission Remote GUI you can also configure a download directory (complete) and a "Directory for incomplete files" (leech).

BUT as soon as I move a download to "seed" ("Set data location..." in transgui) all subsequent downloads go the that directory.
I noticed that transgui seems to remember these settings in transgui.ini as LastMoveDir and LastDownloadDir and I wish it would stop :)

Is there any way around that?

Would it help to automate the manual parts, like copying to the desktop if it's online and moving the data to "seed", probably using transmission-remote on the seedbox?

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case somebody is interested: If you manually confirm the download directory, it's also working.

Answer (score 1):

Just found this lingering in my To-Do list. I got around to automating the process.

I mount my Windows share via `/etc/fstab` to `/trans/incoming`. In `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json` I put the following:

```
"script-torrent-done-enabled": true,
"script-torrent-done-filename": "/trans/done.sh",
```

`/trans/done.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# transmission-daemon ENV VARS:
#
# TR_TORRENT_DIR (example /media/7f2d80ba-2a7c-4708-b601-673b304243fa/downloads)
# TR_TORRENT_NAME (example Arrow.S04E16.HDTV.x264-LOL)
# TR_TORRENT_ID (this is the numeric id that gets displayed at transmission-remote -l), is a number example 15)
#
# Path to copy file to (Fileserver)
copyPath="trans/incoming"
# Path to move files to (Transmission server)
destinationPath="/trans/seed/"

while ! cp -r "$TR_TORRENT_DIR"/"$TR_TORRENT_NAME" "$copyPath"/___PART___"$TR_TORRENT_NAME" ; \
  do now=$(date +"%T") ; echo Error at $now >> /trans/log.done ; \
  sleep 60 ;\
done
mv "$copyPath"/___PART___"$TR_TORRENT_NAME" "$copyPath"/"$TR_TORRENT_NAME"

echo Moved "$TR_TORRENT_NAME" >> /trans/log.done

transmission-remote localhost:9091 -n USER:PASS -t "$TR_TORRENT_ID" --move "$destinationPath"
```

The While-loop is so that the script keeps trying, in case the share is currently unavailable. The PART
prefix is to show that that file is still being copied. And you should probably also configure logrotate to rotate the log file generated by the script, `/trans/log.done`